# pass dynamically generated form name to variable from a function

Tags: jquery

Form name and submit name are all dynamically assigned. When the form is submitted the form action is to call a function php()

Within the jquery function is there anyway to get the form name from which the php() call was made from ?

Note: There is no way for me to know what this would be in advance as the form name is dynamically generated and is always be different.

**The JQUERY**

```
function php() {
    var formname = ????

    alert(formname);
}
```

**THE HTML**

```
<form name="5008000000oYdXIAA0" onsubmit="php();">
  <input type="hidden" name="5008000000oYdXIAA0" value="5008000000oYdXIAA0">
  <input type="submit" name="5008000000oYdXIAA0" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `this` to submit event handler, the `name` can be easily fetched

```js
function php(obj) {
  alert(obj.name)
  return false
}
```

```html
<form name="5008000000oYdXIAA0" onsubmit="return php(this);">
  <input type="hidden" name="5008000000oYdXIAA0" value="5008000000oYdXIAA0">
  <input type="submit" name="5008000000oYdXIAA0" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thank you! seems to work.. will test a little more and come back